# Normalised magnitudes in sliding dft

Tags: fourier-transform, dft

I am new to signal processing. I am trying to use the output of a sliding DFT to analyse frequency peaks. Take for instance this implementation:

https://github.com/bronsonp/SlidingDFT/blob/master/sliding_dft.hpp

How do I find the normalised magnitudes for each SDFT bin?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by normalized magnitude of each bin? Magnitude you can obtain by taking absolute value of the complex value in each bin. To normalize each DFT in a window you can divide by the maximum magnitude in that window.